# Multi-dimension Android project won't build - ProcessInfoBuilder$JavaProcessInfoImpl.getExecutable throws UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, dagger-2

i've got a rather large, multi-dimension Android app that i'm trying to upgrade from Dagger 1 to Dagger 2. i've made all the code changes i believe need to be made to support the upgrade, but now when i build the app i'm getting the following exception (during the **transformClassesWithMultidexlistForXXX** task):

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForMyFlavorAndDimensionDebug'.
> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForMyFlavorAndDimensionDebug'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        ...(snip)...
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessInfoBuilder$JavaProcessInfoImpl.getExecutable(ProcessInfoBuilder.java:349)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.buildProcessException(GradleProcessResult.java:74)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:49)
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.createMainDexList(AndroidBuilder.java:1426)
        ...(snip)...
        ... 68 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5 mins 5.179 secs
Stopped 0 compiler daemon(s).
```

digging into the [source](https://github.com/zeldin/platform_tools_base/blob/master/sdk-common/src/main/java/com/android/ide/common/process/ProcessInfoBuilder.java), `ProcessBuilder.JavaProcessInfoImpl.getExecutable()` simply throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

i'm using version 2.2.3 of the Android Gradle plug-in.

has anyone else run into this issue? have i done something in error to lead me down this path?

any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

*********************** **UPDATE** ***********************

i managed my way around this issue by downgrading from Dagger 2.8 —> 2.7.

Comment: Perhaps you can add a list of dependencies in your project?

Comment: @DavidRawson - thanks for taking an interest. though i still don't know what the root of the problem is, i was able to avoid it by downgrading my Dagger dependencies from 2.8 —> 2.7

Comment: I'm glad you could solve it. If you wanted to pursue it further you would probably have to create an [mcve] as an Android project